# javascript apply not firing each index in array passed into it

Tags: javascript

Why does  `objA.myf3.apply(this,a);` only console.log the first index in the array `a`

how am I using apply wrong  i'm expecting myf3:function(myarr) to be called for each index in the array

and am expecting it to log 
1
2
3
4
......

Thanks for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var objA = {

            myf3:function(myarr){

                console.log(myarr); // why does only the first index of the array come through?

            }
        };


        var objB = {

            myfb2:function(){

                var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

                objA.myf3.apply(this,a);

            }
        };

        objB.myfb2();

    </script>
</head>

<body>

test apply?????

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) will break the array parameter and passes the individual values as parameters. So, in this case, you would have got 9 parameters. You can confirm this by do this

```
myf3:function(myarr) {
        console.log(arguments); // arguments will print all the parameters passed
     }
```

So, you should use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) here

```
objA.myf3.call(this, a);
```

it will pass the parameters as they are.

```
var objA = {
    myf3: function(myarr) {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
};
var objB = {
    myfb2: function() {
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        objA.myf3.apply(this, a);
    }
};
objB.myfb2();
# { '0': 1,
#   '1': 2,
#   '2': 3,
#   '3': 4,
#   '4': 5,
#   '5': 6,
#   '6': 7,
#   '7': 8,
#   '8': 9 }
```

But when we use `.call`,

```
var objA = {
    myf3: function(myarr) {
        console.log(myarr);
    }
};
var objB = {
    myfb2: function() {
        var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        objA.myf3.call(this, a);
    }
};
objB.myfb2();
# [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```